# Why is sage Krishna DvaipAyana known as Veda VyAsa & what is his relation with Beas river?

Tags: mahabharata, culture, identification-request, name, vyasa

In Mahabharata the name "Krishna DvaipAyana" (Dark skinned, Island born) is used quite a lot. Yet the other usage of "[Veda VyAsa](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vyasa)" is more famous.

What's the origin of this second name?

Is the Punjab originated river "[Beas](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beas_River)" (Bias) which is said to be misnomer (अपभ्रंश) of VyAsa was indeed created by this Rishi?

Comment: vyas = divide. veda = vedas

Answer (score 2):

Answering only your one Question **Why is sage Krishna DvaipAyana known as Veda VyAsa?**

Veda Vyasa is not a name but a post. As per [Vishnu Purana](http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/vishnu_purana/veda_vyasa_and_significance_of_brahmagyan.html),

> During every Dwapar Yuga of the present Vaivasvat Manvantara,
> different Vyasas have divided the Vedas twenty-eight times. During the
> first Dwapar, Brahma himself had divided the Vedas. During the second
> Dwapar, Prajapati was Veda Vyasa. During the third Dwapar,
> Shukracharya was Veda Vyasa, During fourth Dwapar, Brihaspati acted as
> Veda Vyasa.
>
> Description of other sages who acted as Veda Vyasa during the
> subsequent Dwapars is as follows- Surya- fifth Veda Vyasa; Mrityu-
> sixth Veda Vyasa, Indra- seventh Veda Vyasa, Vashishta- eighth Veda
> Vyasa, Saraswat- ninth Veda Vyasa, Tridhama- tenth Veda Vyasa,
> Trishikh- eleventh Veda Vyasa, Bharadwaj- twelfth Veda Vyasa,
> Antariksh- thirteenth Veda Vyasa, Varani- fourteenth Veda Vyasa. Names
> of next fourteen Veda Vyasas are as follows- Trayyarun, Dhananjay,
> Krutunjay, Jay, Bharadwaj, Gautam, Haryatma, Vajshrava, Trinbindhu,
> Riksh (Valmiki), Shakti, Parashar, Jatukarn and Krishnadwaipayan.
> After Krishnadwaipayan, Drona's son, Ashwatthama will be the next Veda
> Vyasa.

Here is the Sanskrit shloka for Krishna DvaipAyana as Vyasa:

> [image]

List of Vyasas is given in few other Puranas too, for example [Kurma Purana](http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/kurma_purana/veda_vyasa.html):

> [image]

Comment: Thanks for the details. Anything on the Beas river?

Comment: Wiki says this is Vipasa river in Sanskrit...if so Vashishta tried to sucied in a river but the Rishi rose from the bank, freed from the cords with which he had tied himself. And because his cords were thus broken off by the violence of the current, the Rishi called the stream by the name of Vipasa (the cord-breaker).. Reference of Vipasa are found in Valmiki Ramayana too thus it doesn't seem to be created by Krishna DvaipAyana Ved Vyasa...will add in answer if I find something relevant...as of now it's a partial answer...

Answer (score 2):

Devi Puraana explains why Krishna Dvaipayana is called Veda Vyaasa.

> **Devi Puraana, Book 2 , Chapter 2**
>
> चकार वेदशाखाश्च प्राप्तं ज्ञात्वा कलेर्युगम् ॥ ४३ ॥ 
>   वेदविस्तारकरणाद्व्यासनामाभवन्मुनिः ।
>
> **Seeing the advent of KaliYuga, He divided the Vedas into various Branches.**
>   **As he expanded the Vedas, the Muni got his name as Vyaasa.**